# You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block

Tags: python, django, django-custom-user

I was creating custom user in django for that i wrote following code in initial migration file but when we hit migrate command it gives TransactionManagementError

0001_initial.py

```
from django.db import migrations
from api.user.models import CustomUser

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
def seed_data(apps,schema_editor):
    user = CustomUser(name = "abc",email = "abc@gmail.com",is_staff = True,is_superuser = True,
                       phone = "9874561230",gender = "Male")
    user.set_password("12345")
    user.save()

dependencies = [

]

operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(seed_data),
]
```

error occcured:

```
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You 
can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't execute queries until end of atomic block in my data migration on django 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205220/cant-execute-queries-until-end-of-atomic-block-in-my-data-migration-on-django-1)

Answer (score 2):

This question will be repeated. Please try this reference.

Reference:
[Can't execute queries until end of atomic block in my data migration on django 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205220/cant-execute-queries-until-end-of-atomic-block-in-my-data-migration-on-django-1?rq=1)